# Removing elements after DOM is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a few fields that a user can fill in (e.g., name, number, address), then they can click "Add" which creates a div that displays the information they just entered with a "Remove" button (a href) for each entry. The problem I'm having is that once the DOM is ready, the remove buttons do not work. I've hardcoded a remove button that removes the 3rd div (3rd is arbitrary), and that works, but not the ones that are generated after the page is loaded. My question is how can I have the remove buttons work after the DOM is ready?

Here is the remove function (id is passed in, so it knows which div to remove):

```
function remove(id) {
    $("div.reviewSub"+id).remove();
}
```

And here is the handler to call the function:

```
$(".remove").click(function(event) {remove(event.target.id);});
```

The way I display the data after it has been retrieved is with `.append()`:

```
$(".reviewSub"+num).append("<a href=\"#\" class=\"remove\" id=\"" + num + "\">Remove</a>");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `live` method in jQuery.

```
$('.remove').live('click', function(event){
    remove(event.target.id); 
});
```

I suspect that you have the code `$(".remove").click(function(event) {remove(event.target.id);});` before you are appending the DOM. As a result, jQuery has not been able to bind the click event to the element as the element doesnt exist yet.

More documentation here http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Okay, I'll play around with it a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, can you perhaps elaborate on what you mean by $('.remove')...?

Comment: it was just your line of code without the whole thing :P I will edit the answer :)

Comment: Ah, I see. :] Hmm, do you think anything is wrong with how I'm appending it? I'm still not getting any functionality from the $('.remove').live code. I added a simple alert in that instead of a function call, but nothing happens.

Comment: I know the problem. live was added in v1.3, and the site I'm working on (Drupal) has 1.2.6